# paginator.posts not working in Jekyll-paginate-v2 on Github Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-paginator

I am facing this weird issue with **Jekyll-paginate-v2**.
The paginator.posts is working locally but when I update the site on GitHub repo. It doesn’t work on both index.html & blog.html **(**Inside ***_pages*** Folder**)**

Here are the files,

***_config.yml***

```
pagination:
  enabled: true 
  collection: 'posts'
  permalink: '/page/:num/' 
  category: 'posts' 
  per_page: 3 
  sort_reverse: true 
  sort_field: 'date' 
  title: 'Blog' 
  limit: 0 
  tag: '' 
   
  trail:
    before: 2
    after: 2
  extension: html 

plugins:
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-paginate-v2
  - jekyll-redirect-from
```

***index.html***

```
---
layout: default
pagination: 
  enabled: true
  collection: posts
---

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 mt-4">
                <div class="row">

            {% for post in paginator.posts %}
      <div class="col-lg-4 my-5 post indexposts">
        <img class="post-img img-fluid" title="{{post.title}}" alt="{{post.title}}" src="{{site.url}}/assets/img/posts/{{ post.slug }}/thumbnail.png">
        <div class="post-body">
          <div class="post-meta">
            <a class="post-category tag" href="#">{{post.tags}}</a>
            <span class="post-date"><time datetime="{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</time></span>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the [link to my site](https://webomonk.com/).

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just want to bring your attention that `jekyll-paginate-v2` is not supported by GitHub pages.

[image]

Try [`jekyll-paginate`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-paginate).